# Why is the image of a C*-Algebra complete?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I am currently working through the book by Bratteli and Robinson on C* and W* algebras, there is one point at the beginning of chapter 2.3 that is frustrating me.

If we take *-morphism to be a function $\pi: U \to B$ between $C^*$-algebras $U,V$ with:

1. $\pi$ is linear and multiplicative
2. $\forall A \in U,$ $\pi(A^*)=\pi(A)^*$

Then a property is of such a map is $||\pi(A)||≤||A||$ (so contractive and as such continuous).

The book remarks that the image of $U$ is closed by "an easy" application of this continuity property. However I cannot reach the result and I feel like I am failing to do something extremely obvious. Does anybody have any tips?

(It is maybe interesting to note that in the [erratum](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-09089-3_3) they comment that the line "by an easy" is to be omitted! One more comment: Since $U$ and $V$ are complete normed vector spaces, I am taking it to be equivalent for a subset to be complete or closed)

Comment: This follows from the fact that the quotient of a $C^*$-algebra by a closed 2-sided $*$-ideal is again a $C^*$-algebra, and the fact that an injective homomorphism of $C^*$-algebras is an isometry.  Neither of these facts is trivial, though.

Comment: @EricWofsey: "an injective homomorphism of C*-algebras is an isometry." What do you mean with this? Inclusions are injective and *-morphisms, but not necessarily bijections.

Comment: Isometry just means it preserves the norm, not necessarily that it is surjective.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, for some reason I understood isomorphism.

Comment: @EricWofsey: may I suggest that you write your answer as such, and not as a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on my comment, let us take as given the following two (nontrivial) facts:

> **Lemma 1**: If $U$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $I\subset U$ is a closed 2-sided $*$-ideal, then $U/I$ is a $C^*$-algebra.
>
> **Lemma 2**: If $U$ and $V$ are $C^*$-algebras and $\pi:U\to V$ is an injective $*$-morphism, then $\|\pi(A)\|=\|A\|$ for all $A\in U$.

Now suppose $\pi:U\to V$ is any $*$-morphism of $C^*$-algebras; we wish to show $\pi(U)$ is closed.  Let $I$ be the kernel of $\pi$; then $\pi$ factors through an injective $*$-morphism $\pi':U/I\to V$.  By Lemma 1, $U/I$ is also a $C^*$-algebra, so we can apply Lemma 2 to $\pi'$ and conclude that $\pi'$ is an isometry.  In particular, this implies the image of $\pi'$ is closed.  But the image of $\pi'$ is the same as the image of $\pi$, hence the image of $\pi$ is closed.

Let me now briefly sketch the proofs of the lemmas.  In Lemma 1, it suffices to show that the usual quotient norm satisfies the $C^*$ identity.  This can be shown by some calculations using an approximate identity for $I$ (the idea being that the best way to approximate $A\in U$ by elements of $I$ is to take $AB_\alpha$, where $B_\alpha\in I$ is an approximate identity for $I$).   In Lemma 2, you can use the $C^*$ identity to reduce to the case that $A$ is self-adjoint, in which case the norms of $A$ and $\pi(A)$ can be computed as the spectral radius.  It thus suffices to show that $\pi$ preserves spectra of self-adjoint elements.  This can be shown using the continuous functional calculus (if $\sigma(A)$ were strictly larger than $\sigma(\pi(A))$, you could find two continuous functions on $\sigma(A)$ that agree on $\sigma(\pi(A))$, and this contradicts injectivity of $\pi$).