# Morphism: Unitization

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given C*-Algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.
*(Possibly unital!)*

Morphisms are contractive:
$$\varphi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}:\quad\|\varphi\|\leq1$$
*(Possibly nonunital!)*

How to apply unitization?

Comment: If $\mathcal A$ has unit $\mathbb 1$, then your embedding into $\mathcal{B(A)}$ sends $(-\mathbb 1)\oplus1$ to the map $X \mapsto (-\mathbb 1)X+X=0$. So you have elements of zero norm, and this is not a normed space.

Comment: @s.harp: Hmm so the embedding fails already when I have a left (right) identity. Do you think there's a way out?

Comment: The contractive property of $*$-morphisms can be proven without adjoining any identities. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @s.harp: Yes, that is my primary concern. How does the proof work then?

Comment: I guess you do adjoin identities in the proof, so that comment is not correct. But I have written up how it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to show contractivity usually works like this:

If $\Phi : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ is a $*$-morphism between $C^*$ Algebras, you can assume in general $\mathcal A$ to be unital (otherwise append unit to $\mathcal A$ and extend $\Phi$ so that $\Phi(\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal A})=\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal B}$, if $\mathcal B$ is not unital then extend it also to make this work). In that case if you define $\pi= \Phi(\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal A})$ you have $\pi^2=\pi=\pi^*$, and either $\pi=0$ or $\pi$ is a projection of norm $1$.

You can then see that the image of $\mathcal A$ under $\Phi$ is a subset of $\mathcal B':=\pi \mathcal B \pi$ (because $\Phi(A)=\Phi(\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal A} A \mathbb{1}_{\mathcal A})=\pi\Phi(A)\pi$). $\pi$ is a unit in $\mathcal B'$ and $\mathcal B'$ is a $C^*$ algebra, completeness in the metric sense follows from:

$$\pi A_n \pi -B \to 0 \implies \pi (\pi A_n \pi - B)\pi = \pi A_n \pi - \pi B \pi \to 0$$

And you have reduced to the case of a unital $*$-morphism. I'll add the proof of that case for completeness:

If $A \in \mathcal A$ then $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(A)\supset \sigma_\mathcal{B'} (\Phi(A))$, because unitary morphisms conserve invertibility.

In the case of a self-adjoint $A$ you then have $\|A\|=\sup \sigma_{\mathcal A}(A)$ and $\|\Phi(A)\|=\sup \sigma_\mathcal{B'} (\Phi(A))≤\|A\|$.

If $A$ is not self adjoint, $A^*A$ is so and $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|≥\|\Phi(A^*A)\|=\|\Phi(A)^*\Phi(A)\|=\|\Phi(A)\|^2$.

Comment: But what if both have a unit but the *-morphisms does not respect the units?

Comment: @Freeze_S the whole point of the construction of $\mathcal B'$ is that $\Phi$ does not need to be unital. The closure of the range is a subset of $\mathcal B'$, so you could take that too. An aside: The image of $*$-morphism (into a $C^*$ Algebra) is in general closed, so the image of a $*$-morphism is a $C^*$ algebra.

Comment: I just noticed: Can't I simply take the closure of the range? _(It is clearly a C*-algebra with unit.)_

Comment: Does it maybe hold $\overline{\mathcal{R}\varphi}=1_\mathcal{R}\mathcal{B}1_\mathcal{R}$ for $1_\mathcal{R}:=\varphi(1_\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: That the range is closed, isn't that only *a posteriori*?

Comment: @Freeze_S no (two the second statement), take $\mathcal A = \mathbb C$, $\mathcal B$ $n\times n$ matrices and $\Phi(1)=\mathbb 1_n$. Then $1_\mathcal{R}=1_\mathcal B$ and $1_\mathcal{R}\mathcal B1_\mathcal{R}=\mathcal B \neq \Phi(\mathcal A)$.

Comment: @Freeze_S yes, I think usually you use contractiveness to show that the image is closed. Specifically Lemma 2 here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400305/why-is-the-image-of-a-c-algebra-complete uses it I think.

Comment: Good point! Ok but then still isn't it much simpler to simply restrict the final C*-algebra to the (closure of the) range so the *-morphism becomes unital.

Comment: Yes, that is right. $\pi$ remains a unit in the closure since $\pi A - A=\lim_\alpha \left(\pi A_\alpha -A_\alpha\right) = 0$

Comment: In any case: Thanks alot alot!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

*Extending s.sharp's answer..*

**Algebra**

Given a C*-Algebra $1_\mathcal{Z}\notin\mathcal{Z}$.

Unitization:
$$\iota_\mathcal{Z}:\mathcal{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{Z}\oplus\mathbb{C}:\quad\iota_\mathcal{Z}Z:=Z\oplus0$$
$$\pi_\mathcal{Z}:\mathcal{Z}\oplus\mathbb{C}\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal{Z}:\quad\pi_\mathcal{Z}(Z\oplus\lambda):=Z$$

Isometricity:
$$\|\iota_\mathcal{Z}Z\|=\|Z\|\quad\|\pi_\mathcal{Z}(Z\oplus0)\|=\|Z\|$$

*(Nonunital crucial!)*

**Morphism**

Extension:
$$\Phi:\mathcal{A}(\oplus\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\oplus\mathbb{C}):\quad\Phi A(\oplus\lambda):=\varphi A\left(+\lambda1_{\mathcal{B}(\oplus\mathbb{C})}\right)$$

Range-Unit:
$$1_\mathcal{R}:=\Phi1_{\mathcal{A}(\oplus\mathbb{C})}:\quad 1_\mathcal{R}R\equiv R\equiv R1_\mathcal{R}\quad(R\in\overline{\mathcal{R}\Phi})$$

Restriction:
$$\Phi_\mathcal{R}:\mathcal{A}(\oplus\mathbb{C})\to\overline{\mathcal{R}\Phi}:\quad\Phi_\mathcal{R}A(\oplus\lambda):=\Phi A(\oplus\lambda)$$

Unit-Preserving:
$$\Phi_\mathcal{R}1_{\mathcal{A}(\oplus\mathbb{C})}=\Phi1_{\mathcal{A}(\oplus\mathbb{C})}=1_\mathcal{R}$$

Action-Identic:
$$\varphi=(\pi_\mathcal{B}\circ)\Phi(\circ\iota_\mathcal{A})
=(\pi_\mathcal{B}\circ)\Phi_\mathcal{R}(\circ\iota_\mathcal{A})$$
*(Modulo Ranges!)*